# message broker about ws-event demo

Tags: wso2, messagebroker

message broker about ws-event demo
q1:
http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2012/06/publishing-messages-message-broker-using-event-mediator

how a client call proxyservice

q2:
Event Sink URL target service demo

Answer (score 0):

Q1 : You can use soap UI to call a proxy service. For that you can get the endpoint url from the service listing page in ESB. I think [this](http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/your-first-soapui-project.html) will be helpful to you.

Q2 : Not clear on the question.